# Positioning div in bottom left with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm running into some difficulty positioning an element in the bottom left corner when using a flexbox.
Essentially I'm trying to make the 'world' text to appear directly below the 'hello' text (ie. the bottom left corner of the flexbox).

```css
rel {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
abs {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
}
column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<column>
  <item>
    hello
    <br>hello
    <br>hello
    <br>hello
    <br>
    <rel>
      <abs>
        world
        <br/>world
        <br/>world
        <br/>world
        <br/>
      </abs>
    </rel>
  </item>
</column>
```

Comment: Like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/c5cbxw9q/1/)?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? What I did was make `item` display as flex column as well which will make additional elements fall under it as a column. Also added `align-items: flex-start;` to `column` so they are aligned properly. You can also remove the position properties as they aren't needed.

**[Live Demo on jsfiddle, snippet below.](https://jsfiddle.net/c5cbxw9q/2/)**

**CSS Changes**

```
column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
rel{
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  padding:5px;
}

abs{
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  padding:5px;
}

column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<column>
 <item>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  hello<br>
  <rel>
   <abs>
    world<br/>
    world<br/>
    world<br/>
    world<br/>
   </abs>
  </rel>
 </item>
</column>
```

Comment: While that does get the desired result, I need the absolute positioning as the 'worlds' will be over other text and shouldn't disturb the content.

Comment: @Robbie so something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/c5cbxw9q/3/ where you just add `absolute` back?

Comment: Yep, I didn't even think that the entire thing was now relative to the flex box, so all you needed was to change the relative to a absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column;`to the `item` tag. Also removing the padding will perfectly match the edges. That is the direct container that holds all the elements. Also you can remove the absolute and relative positions.

```css
rel {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px;
}
abs {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<column>
  <item>
    hello
    <br>hello
    <br>hello
    <br>hello
    <br>
    <rel>
      <abs>
        world
        <br/>world
        <br/>world
        <br/>world
        <br/>
      </abs>
    </rel>
  </item>
</column>
```